# display shapes where user clicks in react konva

Tags: reactjs, canvas, react-konva

I am a complete beginner in react konva and trying to make a simple project. I just want to display a rectangle wherever user clicks so like if user clicked at 3 position he can see 3 rectangle on the canvas.
How can I achieve this?

I found this code in sandbox and added a onmousedown handleclick function but have no idea what to do next

any help is much appreciated

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Konva from "konva";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Stage, Layer, Rect, Text } from "react-konva";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    cursor: {
      x: null,
      y: null
    }
  };
  handleClick = (e) => {
    alert("mouseclicked");
  };
  handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    var stage = e.currentTarget;
    stage = this.stageRef.getStage();
    stage = e.target.getStage();
    this.setState({
      cursor: stage.getPointerPosition()
    });
  };

  render() {
    const text = `cursor position : ${this.state.cursor.x}, ${this.state.cursor.y}`;
    return (
      <Stage
        onMouseDown={this.handleClick}
        width={window.innerWidth}
        height={window.innerHeight}
        onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}
        ref={(ref) => {
          this.stageRef = ref;
        }}
      >
        <Layer>
          <Text text={text} x={50} y={100} fontSize={20} />
          
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a state for created rectangles, add new data into state on click and draw shapes from that state in render function.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Konva from "konva";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Stage, Layer, Rect, Text } from "react-konva";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    cursor: {
      x: null,
      y: null
    },
    rectangles: []
  };
  handleClick = (e) => {
    const newRect = {
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      fill: Konva.Util.getRandomColor(),
      x: e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition().x,
      y: e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition().y
    };
    const rectangles = [...this.state.rectangles, newRect];
    this.setState({ rectangles });
  };
  handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    var stage = e.currentTarget;
    stage = this.stageRef.getStage();
    stage = e.target.getStage();
    this.setState({
      cursor: stage.getPointerPosition()
    });
  };

  render() {
    const text = `cursor position : ${this.state.cursor.x}, ${this.state.cursor.y}`;
    return (
      <Stage
        onMouseDown={this.handleClick}
        width={window.innerWidth}
        height={window.innerHeight}
        onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}
        ref={(ref) => {
          this.stageRef = ref;
        }}
      >
        <Layer>
          <Text text={text} x={50} y={100} fontSize={20} />
          {this.state.rectangles.map((shape) => (
            <Rect {...shape} />
          ))}
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-add-shapes-on-click-n0641?file=/src/index.js